# Understanding a lemma about a finitely generated group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

There is a "lemma" in the book about group theory I'm seeing that states the following:

> A group $G$ is said to be finitely generated if $G$ contains a finite
>   subset $S$ such that $G = \langle S \rangle$. Note that if $S:=\{s_1,...,s_k\}$ and $G = \langle S \rangle$ is abelian then $$G=\{s_1^{n_1}...s_k^{n_k}:n_j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

There is no proof about this, and I don't understand it. Any hints?

Comment: Which part? The claim has two inclusions, so which is is the issue?

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: $G \supset \{s_1^{n_1}...s_k^{n_k}:n_j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is obvious I guess, since every element of $S$ can be written as one of $\langle S \rangle$ by taking the exponents equal to 1 and just one element. So I guess the other inclusion is the one I don't get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see by a comment in another answer that you are using a slightly different definition of $<S>$ as I am.

I'm using if $<S> = \{\prod t_i\}$ where $t_i$ is either a $s\in S$ or a $s^{-1}$ of an $s\in S$ and the product can be any combination thereof.

If $G$ is abelian then  if you "clump" the same $s_i$s and $s_i^{-1}$ to be sequential then $<S>= \{\prod s_k^{n_i} \}$ ($n\in \mathbb Z$).

But you are using $<S>$ is the smallest group that contains $S$.

If $G$ is abelian it's easy to see $\{\prod s_k^{n_k} \}$ is a group.  ($e = s_1^0$ and for every $g=\prod s_k^{n_k}$ then $g^{-1} = \prod s_k^{-n_k}$)

And if for any supgroup $K$ if $S\subset K$ then every $\prod s_k^{n_k}\in  K$. so $\{\prod s_k^{n_k} \}\subset K$.

So $\{\prod s_k^{n_k} \}$ is the smallest subgroup containing $S$.

====

Well if $S= \{s_1, ...., s_k\}$ then $<S>$ then $G$ consists $s_{k_1}^{a_1}*s_{k_2}^{a_2}*s_{k_3}^{a_3}*.......*s_{k_z}^{a_z}$ where $a_i = \pm 1$ $\{k_1,k_2,k_3\}$ can be any sequence of indexes including the possibility of $k_{n+1} = k_n$.  These are any product of elements of $S$ and inverses of elements of $S$.

If $G$ is abelian then we can rearrange all the component terms so elements are next to each other.

So if $n =s_{k_1}^{a_1}*s_{k_2}^{a_2}*s_{k_3}^{a_3}*.......$ we can rearrange the terms to $n = \underbrace{s_1^{a_{1_1}}*s_1^{a_{1_2}}*.... s_1^{a_{1_{n_1}}}}\underbrace{s_2^{a_{2_1}}*s_2^{a_{2_2}}*.... s_2^{a_{2_{n_2}}}}.....\underbrace{s_k^{a_{k_1}}*s_k^{a_{k_2}}*.... s_m^{a_{k_{n_k}}}}=s_1^{n_1}*s_2^{n_2}*...*s_k^{n_k}$

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since $G=\langle S\rangle$ is abelian and $S\subseteq G$, we have $s_is_j=s_js_i$ for all $1\le i,  j\le k$. Thus we can move each of the generators past one another, so that we are left with $$G=\{s_1^{n_1}...s_k^{n_k}:n_j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ because every element of $G$ can be written in terms of the generators.

Comment: So you are proving it immediately, without showing the double inclusion?

Comment: Yes, @AngusL. I'm using the definition of abelian and of $G=\langle S\rangle$.

Comment: How do you define $\langle S \rangle$? Because until this lemma the only definition I have seen of a generated group is that it if S is a subset of G, then $\langle S \rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of G that contains S

Comment: Ah, I see, @AngusL; my definition is that $\langle S\rangle$ for $S\subseteq G$ is the group of all products in $G$ of elements in $S$, and their inverses. Showing that this is equivalent to your definition is fairly straightforward. I'm confident it has been proven before on this site, so I'll leave it to you as an exercise.

Comment: "Because until this lemma the only definition I have seen of a generated group is that it if S is a subset of G, then ⟨S⟩ is the smallest subgroup of G that contains S"  That should make it easier.  $\{s_1^{n_1}...s_k^{n_k}\}$ is easily shown to be a group. And and if any $s_{k_1}^{m_1}..s_{k_j}^{m_j}$ is *not* in a subgroup $M$ then at least one of the $s_{k_l}$ are not in $M$.  So $\{s_1^{n_1}...s_k^{n_k}\}$ is the smallest group with $S$ as a subset.  However it has to be abelian for us to be able to "clump" like terms together.

Comment: I think I got it, thanks!